# I have several textboxes, when user inputs TAB or SHIFT+TAB, I'd like him to be able to navigate these

Tags: wpf

In a short XAML, I have several textboxes. At the moment, when user inputs TAB or SHIFT+TAB, a **\t** gets added in the textbox. I would like this to not happen, and rather let him navigate through the textboxes using these keys.

Is this possible in pure XAML ?

Comment: That happens by default. Can you post your code or a sample that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [AcceptsTab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.acceptstab.aspx) property

```
<TextBox AcceptsTab="false" />
```